# Overriding Laravel's method

Tags: php, laravel, overriding

Given the route:

```
 Route::get('verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify');
```

It uses the Laravel's default verify method from

```
auth-backend/VerifiesEmails.php
```

The default `verify` method looks like bellow:

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user()->getKey())) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
        throw new AuthorizationException;
    }

    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 204)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    if ($response = $this->verified($request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 204)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
}
```

I would like to change **only** the last block of the code in the verify method from

```
        return $request->wantsJson()
                ? new Response('', 204)
                : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('verified', true);
```

to

```
    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new Response('', 204)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with([
            'verified' => true,
            'userNotification' => [
                'message' => 'Wellcome to my website',
                'title' => 'Hello World',
            ],
        ]);
```

I know I can override the whole `verify` method in the VerificationController, which is not ideal to copy and paste the whole block of code for a small change.
My question is **How can override only the last block of code as mentioned above?**

Answer (score 2):

Right before the final return there is this block:

```
if ($response = $this->verified($request)) {
return $response;
```

}

So in your `VerificationController` you can override just the `verified` method which is meant for that.

If you look into its source you will see it:

[source](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/444072cb2f8baaa15172c5cde2bd30d188c3b7e7/auth-backend/VerifiesEmails.php#L64-L73)

So in your local VerificationController add:

```
protected function verified(Request $request)
{
    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new Response('', 204)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath())->with([
            'verified' => true,
            'userNotification' => [
                'message' => 'Wellcome to my website',
                'title' => 'Hello World',
            ],
        ]);
}
```